# Replace 0 - 10 numbers in string with words in C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

The issue I am facing is I have to replace 0 - 10 with their respective word like "2" - two, from the input which will be a string.
Example:
When the input says "11 apples and 2 mangoes" the output I get is "oneone apples and two mangoes".
Expected Output:
"11 apples and two mangoes".
Here is an attempt of mine which failed.

```
 string str = Console.ReadLine();
                string[] strArr = str.split(" ");
                Regex rgx = new Regex("^[0-9]{2}");
                var val = rgx.isMatch(strAtr[i]);
                if(!val){
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
                        sb.Replace("0", "zero");
                        sb.Replace("1", "one");
                        sb.Replace("2", "two");
                        sb.Replace("3", "three");
                        sb.Replace("4", "four");
                        sb.Replace("5", "five");
                        sb.Replace("6", "six");
                        sb.Replace("7", "seven");
                        sb.Replace("8", "eight");
                        sb.Replace("9", "nine");
                        sb.Replace("10", "ten");
                      }
                       Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: I would recommand you to use a regex to matcher the number, then use a switch case like method in order to pick the correct string to replace the matched number with. Look like homework :)

Comment: Is `11 apples` an example the problem gave you? Put another way, what does the problem say `11` should be replaced with? If it doesn't specify, then `oneone` might be correct.

Comment: 11 is not a number here its a string "11 apples" and I need to replace only 0 to 10.

Comment: So for `"11 apples"` should the output be`oneone apples` or not?

Comment: No, it should ignore in this case and gives the output the same as input "11 apples" but when the input is "I have 2 apples and 3 mangoes" then the output will be "I have two apples and three mangoes".

Comment: So you need to replace the **word** '1' with "one", rather than the **character** '1'

Comment: Yes it should take a whole word as 11 not 1 then 1

Comment: Doesn't this code return 'onezero apples' instead of 'ten apples'?

Comment: @stuartd: no, because the OP has a "10" :: "ten" relationship defined.  If he/she wants to get "11" to return "eleven", then "eleven" (etc.) would need to be defined.  The rules for English numbers are a little complicated (see my answer).  Be thankful you aren't working in French.

Comment: Oh, the question has changed since I started writing out my answer.  You want "5 mangos and 11 apples" to get translated to "five mangos and 11 apples" - I had assumed you wanted "five mangos and eleven apples".  So, what you want to do is change your Regex so that it picks up any number of consecutive digits as a group.  Then parse the group to a number (which _should just work_).  If the number is <=10, do your replace work, otherwise, don't

Comment: @Flydog57 it does indeed return 'oneten apples' (once it's fixed up to actually run) - because the replacement for `10` occurs after the replacement of `0` and `1`..

Comment: @stuartd, after hacking at his code to get it to compile (fixing capitalization issues, spelling, code like `strAtr[i]` and the backwards logic in the `if` statement), I get "oneone apples".  The `StringBuilder.Replace` method (unlike `string.Replace`) does its work in place.  It also does it globally.  So, `sb.Replace("1", "one")` will replace both `1`s with `one`.  None of the other `Replace` calls fire.  My code (in my answer below) does what I believe he wants to do.  I show before and after versions of the input string, copy/pasted from running code.

Comment: I don't get it @Flydog57 - what am I missing here? https://dotnetfiddle.net/z2aLpJ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216605/discussion-between-flydog57-and-stuartd).

Comment: So, did my answer work for you? The only way the next person looking for a solution to a problem like yours would know if my answer is any good is if you *Accept* it or *Up Vote* it. Someone voted it down, but it works the way I believe you want it to work. If one of the other answers works for you  *Accept* it or *Up Vote* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm leaving my original answer below, it's a nice answer to the question that it looked like you were asking until you clarified things in the comments.

I believe this answers your question:

```
 const string mangoesPattern = @"\d+";
 var mangoesRegex = new Regex(mangoesPattern);
 const string mangoesSource = "I have 5 apples, 11 mangoes, 675 oranges, 3 grapes and 27 coconuts";

 var mangoesDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
 {
     {0, "zero"},
     {1, "one"},
     {2, "two"},
     {3, "three"},
     {4, "four"},
     {5, "five"},
     {6, "six"},
     {7, "seven"},
     {8, "eight"},
     {9, "nine"},
     {10, "ten"},
 };

 var mangoesMatches = mangoesRegex.Matches(mangoesSource);
 var buffer = new StringBuilder();
 var lastProcessedIndex = 0;
 var originalStringLength = mangoesSource.Length;

 foreach (var match in mangoesMatches.Cast<Match>())
 {
     var numGroup = match.Groups[0];
     var num = int.Parse(numGroup.ToString());       //it's necessarily a number, so it should work
     if (mangoesDictionary.ContainsKey(num))
     {
         buffer.Append(mangoesSource.Substring(lastProcessedIndex, numGroup.Index - lastProcessedIndex));
         buffer.Append(mangoesDictionary[num]);
         lastProcessedIndex = numGroup.Index + numGroup.Length;
     }
 }

 //pick up the rest of the string
 buffer.Append(mangoesSource.Substring(lastProcessedIndex, originalStringLength - lastProcessedIndex));
```

It looks for any integer sub-strings in your source string, and then walks through the matches and groups, checking to see if there is a translation between the value of the integer and a number you want translated.  If there is, it does the substitution.

After translation, the original source:

```
I have 5 apples, 11 mangoes, 675 oranges, 3 grapes and 27 coconuts
```

Ends up as:

```
I have five apples, 11 mangoes, 675 oranges, three grapes and 27 coconuts
```

---

**Here's my original answer**, when I thought your question was about "How to translate numbers to text".

*By the way, you really need to flesh out your question.  Read over all the comments and fix up your question.  Use my apples and mangoes string as an example of your desired behavior*

---

This looks like a homework assignment.  I don't do other folks' homework, but I will give a boat-load of hints as an answer.

First consider the problem space:

- The numbers 0-19 are special, and really need to be handled the way you are doing in the code you show (as a set of strings representing numbers)
- Starting at 20 and continuing up to 99, you can take the first digit, give it a name (like "thirty") and take on one of the numbers from the first rule (so that 43 becomes "forty", "three")
- When you get to 100, you take the first digit, apply the first rule, add the string "hundred" and then tack on the number that represents the last two digits from the first two rules (so that 823 becomes "eight", "hundred" "twenty", "three").
- Between 1000 and 999,999, you treat the thousands part as if it's a one to three digit number, put "thousand" after that, and then the name of the three digit number that follows (the ones/tens/hundreds part).  As a result 236,117 becomes "two", "hundred", "thirty", "six", "thousand", "one", "hundred", "seventeen"
- Millions, billions, etc. all follow the same rules as thousands, adding more information to the front of the number.

That should be enough to get you writing some code.

If you think about it, you don't need to have that many strings.  Twenty for 0-19, then eight more for 20-90.  Then "hundred", "thousand", "million", etc.

Comment: Yes, it worked Thank you and I edited my question too. If the question looks suitable now give an upvote and remove the negativity.